# code in wordpress not working, though it is working on other platforms

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a code where 4 circles are next to each other. It is working on websites like codepen, jsfiddle. But on wordpress it doesn't look the same.

I have asked the question on a wordpress forum, but they couldn't help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/mq2fdbvz/   example on jsfiddle

http://giscience.zgis.at/de/concept-projekte-page/   example on real wordpress webpage

So what is the deal ? Is there something wrong with my code or wordpress ?

edit: the code was already placed in text mode and there are no 
 tags. And the code is working on another wordpress webpage, on this wordpress page it isn't.

```
<style>
.smallmenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 436px;
    width: 100%;
}
.circlemenu {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 106px;
    height: 107px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    border: solid 2px #73B7DB;
    background: #73B7DB;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 440%;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 24pt;">Mit dem Fahrrad zur Schule? Aber sicher!</span></p>
<p style="margin: 2% 20% 2% 20%;">Es gibt viele gute Gründe, mit dem Fahrrad zur Schule zu fahren. Lerne sie kennen und plane deine persönliche, sicherste Route.</p>
&nbsp;
<div class="smallmenu">
    <a class="circlemenu" href="#why" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Warum</font></a>
    <a class="circlemenu" href="#what" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Was</font></a>
    <a class="circlemenu" href="#how" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Wie</font></a>
    <a class="circlemenu" href="#quiz" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Quiz</font></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are pasting your code in Editor mode and wordpress is adding line breaks.

Can be **Fixed** in two ways:

- Place all `href` in single line

  ```
  <div class="smallmenu"> <a class="circlemenu" href="#why" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Warum</font></a> <a class="circlemenu" href="#what" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Was</font></a> <a class="circlemenu" href="#how" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Wie</font></a> <a class="circlemenu" href="#quiz" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Quiz</font></a></div>
  ```
- Paste code in `Text View` instead of `Visual Mode`

Comment: Atlas_Gondal, what do you mean with placing all href in a single line ? You mean putting the a id lines next to each other without any space ?

Comment: I have mentioned reason in answer but here is little more detail for your understanding. Basically, wordpress Visual Mode allows us to make changes without coding knowledge or modification. Like we can make text **bold**, _italic_ etc And your `href` tags was written on separate lines so wordpress was adding line breaks by adding `<br>` tag in output. Hope you understand now! :)

Answer (score 0):

And remove `<br>` between a.circlemenu.

[image]

If you using WordPress editor, try keep it on oneline only. Like this:

```
<a class="circlemenu" href="#why" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Warum</font></a><a class="circlemenu" href="#what" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Was</font></a><a class="circlemenu" href="#how" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Wie</font></a><a class="circlemenu" href="#quiz" id="hovermenu"><font color="white">Quiz</font></a>
```

And remember to change this CSS from:

```
height: 107;
```

to:

```
height: 107px;
```

Comment: I usually do most of the coding on one line, especially the css. Most of the time I have no problem but this time it doesn't work. So your solution about putting the body in one line as well, made the circle go next to each other. The circles are really close to each other now though, but it is better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is there is `</br>` tag in between your div

```
    <a id="hovermenu" class="circlemenu" href="#why">
<font color="white">Warum</font>
</a>
<br>
<a id="hovermenu" class="circlemenu" href="#what">
<font color="white">Was</font>
</a>
<br>
```

Try to eliminate those `<br>` tag. It will solve your problem.